# FMOD API doesn't return the FMOD version properly

Tags: c++, api, fmod

I'm currently trying to embed `FMOD` in my project and I want to get and print the version of `FMOD`.
I done this:

```
#include "fmodmanager.h"
#include "fmod_errors.h"
#include <string>

using namespace FMOD;
EventSystem     *pEventSystem;
Event           *pEvent = NULL;
System          *pSystem;
FMOD_RESULT     result;
CFMODManager gFMODMng;

CFMODManager* FMODManager()
{
    return &gFMODMng;
}

void ERRCHECK(FMOD_RESULT result)
{
    if (result != FMOD_OK)
    {
        WarnMsg("FMod error! (%d) %s\n", result, FMOD_ErrorString(result));
    }
}

CFMODManager::CFMODManager()
{
}

CFMODManager::~CFMODManager()
{
}

// This starts FMOD
void CFMODManager::InitFMOD( void )
{
    ERRCHECK(result = FMOD::EventSystem_Create(&pEventSystem));
    ERRCHECK(result = pEventSystem->init(64, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, 0, FMOD_EVENT_INIT_NORMAL));

    // Print the version
    fmodVersion = pSystem->getVersion(&fmodVersion);
    Msg("FMod initialized (%d)\n", fmodVersion);
}
```

But what I get is:

> FMod initialized (36)

Instead of returning the version, `FMOD` return *36*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FMOD version number is stored as hexadecimal so it's easy to read in memory, i.e. 0x00044421 is easily read as 4.44.21, so you should print it using %x instead of %d.

Also the return from System:::getVersion is actually an FMOD_RESULT error code for the success or failure of the function call, you should not assign it to the version number you a trying to fetch.

Finally, you are getting the FMOD_RESULT 36 (FMOD_ERR_INVALID_HANDLE) because the pSystem pointer you are using hasn't been initialized. You should use EventSystem::getSystemObject after EventSystem_Create to fetch the valid low level system handle.

Answer (score 0):

First, the version number returned by `getVersion()` is an `unsigned int`.
So you should use the **`%u`** type specifier in `printf` (not `%d`).

Moreover, `getVersion()` may return the version number using *some particular format*, e.g. it could "pack" version major number and version minor number in the same unsigned integer. For example, could it be possible that the returned value "36" may mean "version 3.6"?

Comment: Normally, getVersion returns something like "00044421" http://pastebin.com/Zm3KDZkq